# Bayes network example

Tags: conditional-probability

Given the following Bayes net:

[image: BayesNet]

with

- $p(k=t)=.2$
- $p(o=t)=.1$
- $p(s=t|k=f,o=f)=.0$
- $p(s=t|k=f,o=t)=.2$
- $p(s=t|k=t,o=f)=.5$
- $p(s=t|k=t,o=t)=.95$

how would I calculate $p(o=t|k=t)$?

Intuitively I'd say it must be $0.1$, but if I calculate this as a sum of basic probabilities: i.e. $p(s=t|o=t)=p(s=t,o=t,k=f)+p(s=t,o=t,k=t)$ the result is different.

This video also explains that it should be $0.1$, but the question explicitly said it is not $0.1$.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VsesDjAIMmU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. Since no arrows point to either $O$ or $K$, they are independent, so $P(O=T \mid K=T)=P(O=T)=0.1$. Alternatively, you could calculate it the long way as follows:
$$ \begin{align*}
P(O=T \mid K=T) &= \dfrac{P(O=T,K=T)}{P(K=T)} \\
&= \dfrac{\sum_{s\in \{T,F\}}P(O=T,K=T,S=s)}{\sum_{o\in \{T,F\}}\sum_{s\in \{T,F\}}P(O=o,K=T,S=s)} \\
&= \dfrac{P(K=T)P(O=T)\sum_{s\in \{T,F\}}P(S=s \mid O=T,K=T)}{P(K=T)\sum_{o\in \{T,F\}}\sum_{s\in \{T,F\}}P(O=o)P(S=s \mid O=o,K=T)} \\
&= \dfrac{P(K=T)P(O=T)}{P(K=T)} \\
&= P(O=T) \\
&= 0.1
\end{align*} $$

Comment: Thanks. Could it be that $p(s=t|k=f,o=f)=.0$ somehow unblocks the connection between the two variables?

Comment: Hmm. I'm not really sure what you mean by "unblocks the connection". But I don't think so, no. The main reason for independence is due to the structure of the Bayes net diagram.

Comment: It turned out it was a typo in the assignment.